# Adobe Air localconnection not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, air

I am sending messages through local connection web to `Air` application .
IE, Firefox and Safari are successfuly sending messages.

But chrome is failing in sending.(Only when PPAPI)

Why isn't Chrome `PPAPI` Local connection sending message?

Reference:

[LocalConnection  - AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html)

[Unsandbox LocalConnections in Chrome](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/unsandbox-localconnection-chrome.html)

Website flash as3 - send fart

```
private function receivedFromJavaScript(value:String):void 
        {
            //var conn:LocalConnection;
            //trace("JavaScript says: " + value + "\r");
            ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", + value );
            conn = new LocalConnection();
            conn.client = new Object();

            //conn.allowDomain('app#Myapplication');
            //conn.allowInsecureDomain('app#Myapplication')
            conn.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatus);
            conn.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,function(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void
           {
             //trace("ASYNC_ERROR: " + e );
             ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", "ASYNC_ERROR: " + e );
           });
           conn.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,function(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void
           {
               ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", "SECURITY_ERROR: " + e );
               //trace("SECURITY_ERROR: " + e );
           });  

            conn.send("app#Myapplication:taskConnection", "localconnectionHandler", value);
            ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", "conn = " + conn.client.toString() + " / " + conn.domain);
            //conn.close();
        }
```

AIR applcation code

```
try { 
            conn = new LocalConnection();
            conn.allowDomain("*");
            conn.client = this;                                         
                conn.connect("taskConnection");
                trace("yes.");
            } catch (error:ArgumentError) {       
                trace("Can't connect.");       
            }
```

Comment: I tested the sample chat application attached to your 2nd link, and It's working fine. What about you ?

Comment: chat application is web to web connect. It applies to my code but web to AIR connect fail. (Chrome Sandbox added host)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug.
You can use a workaround disabling PPAPI plugin from the settings page:
http://www.maipiusenza.com/LDV/images/hlp_pic41.gif

Here you can read a discussion in the Adobe's forum
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1045650?start=0&tstart=0

I periodically check for a fix, but I'm still waiting!

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the flash file atttributes on your swf file. If you run this:

```
./flashfileattributes mySWFfile.swf –verboseOnly
./flashfileattributes mySWFfile.swf +brokerLocalConnection
```

then local connection works fine in Chrome.